# Content objects not returned in queries run by public guest/site user

Tags: contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

When associating a Salesforce File to an object in the UI, the associated ContentDocumentLink and ContentVersion records are not returned when a public guest/site user queries for them. An internal Salesforce user can query for them fine. We've tried updating sharing settings, changing owners, and verified the query runs in apex without sharing set. The only thing that seems to work is if I recreate those objects in apex, then the user can query for them.

Has anyone run into this? Is there a way for the site user to have access without recreating the objects in apex?

Comment: Your only way out will be to create a Visualforce Page with an Apex Custom Controller that would display the Salesforce CRM Content for the Force.com Site Guest User.

There is a whole lot of cookbooks here: http://developer.force.com/cookbook/category/content/recent

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found a workaround for this issue. Creating a before insert trigger on ContentVersion that sets the Origin field to C, along with a before insert trigger on ContentDocumentLink that sets Visibility to AllUsers, allowed the public force.com site guest user to access the Salesforce File which was uploaded by the out of the box UI. So records started being returned when querying ContentDocumentLink and ContentVersion as the site user after uploading with those trigger changes in place.